# Google video hangouts on 2.3.5 Android phones?

Tags: camera, google-hangouts

Can one use Google's video hangout on a 2.3.5 Android phone with front camera? My phone has both a front camera and a back camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any phone that has a front-facing camera and is running Gingerbread (Android 2.3.x) and above [will be able to join and initiate Hangouts](http://www.androidcentral.com/google-app-set-receive-big-update-will-now-allow-you-initiate-hangouts) with the latest version of [Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) app.